# Is it possible to copy Firefox bookmarks with iOS Safari?

Tags: macos, ios, mobile-safari, firefox

Quite simply I use Firefox sync on both my Macs and want to migrate these bookmarks to my iOS devices, not necessarly sync all the time, just migrate them as they currently are.

Is it possible, and how should I try doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Export the Firefox Bookmarks](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Exporting%20data%20to%20Safari)

> - On the menu bar, click **Bookmarks** and select *Show All Bookmarks* to    open the Library window.
> - From the toolbar on the Library window, click **Import and Backup**    and choose *Export Bookmarks to HTML....*
> - In the Export Bookmarks File window that opens, choose a location    to save the file, which is named *bookmarks.html* by default. The
>     desktop is usually a good spot, but any place that is easy to
>     remember will work.
> - Click the **Save** button. The Export Bookmarks File window will       close. Close the Library window.
>
>   Import the bookmarks.html file into Safari on the Mac by navigating
>     to the **File** menu within Safari, choosing *Import Bookmarks…*, then
>     selecting the file you saved.You may want to delete or archive the
>     existing Safari bookmarks first.

You can now sync Safari on the Mac with Safari on your iOS devices. iCloud syncing will make this two-way and happen over the network, but you can also sync using USB and connecting to iTunes if the bookmarks will change rarely.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ideas:

1. Use [Firefox Home](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/home/)
2. Import bookmarks from FireFox to Safari on one of your Macs and sync them to your iOS devices using iTunes.

Comment: Firefox home is a nice little app, but it is not a browser so for me it fails on that. I will prob go down the iTunes and safari sync at some point, hoping there is another solution out there. Thanks